# Rhythmbox "shuffle" button appearance doesn't seem to change

Tags: themes, rhythmbox

Here are 2 screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVjUo.jpg

A. Just before clicking the "shuffle" button.

B. Just after clicking the "shuffle" button.

I can't see any readily-discernible difference between them.

I reported this as an application bug in bugzilla (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=784682), but

"Making this difference visible is your gtk+ theme's responsibility.  It looks like you're using a dark variant of the ubuntu theme or something, so you should probably report this bug against whatever that is."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you (install and) run `unity-tweak-tool` then under "Appearance -> Themes" you can select a GTK theme.  On my machine there are three themes available: Ambiance (default, what you are seeing), Highcontrast, and Radiance.  Ambiance and Radiance have the problem you noticed, while Highcontrast doesn't, so it's true that Rhythmbox is at least doing *something* to the button that *some* GTK themes are willing to display.  It seems that the Ambiance and Radiance themes are part of the Ubuntu `light-themes` package, so you could report a bug there and see what its maintainers say.